# Prove the Uniqueness of the following

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let f be a continuously differentiable real valued function such that the derivative of f is bounded (by 1). Then how to prove such a function has a unique fixed point?
My Guess: I think this map is a contraction!! but not sure, Please help...!!

Comment: Bounded by $1$ is not enough. Think of $f(x)=x$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x$,$y$ are fixed points. Then $$|x-y|=|f(x)-f(y)|=|f'(c)|\cdot|x-y|<|x-y|,$$ by Lagrange's mean value theorem. Can you conclude now?